# Strange too few template-parameter-lists error

Tags: c++, gcc

```
set<unsigned int> setId;
vector<int> vecNode;
for (size_t i = 0,set<unsigned int>::iterator it = setId.begin(); i < vecNode.size() && it != setId.end(); i++,it++ ){}
```

the compiler report:
error: too few template-parameter-lists

but if I write like this:

```
set<unsigned int> setId;
vector<int> vecNode;
size_t i = 0;
for (set<unsigned int>::iterator it = setId.begin(); i < vecNode.size() && it != setId.end(); i++,it++ ){}
```

the compilation succeeds.

so why?

Comment: All variables in the initializer list of a `for` loop must be the same (and *only*) type. `for(int i=0,j=1; ...` is valid. Your first snippet is not. (And the second solves that issue by moving one of them out of the initializer).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The same reason as why you cannot do

```
int i = 0, float j = 2.64f;  // ERROR!
```

With

```
size_t i = 0, set<unsigned int>::iterator it = setId.begin()
```

you are actually doing something like the above example, you are defining two variables but with different types, namely `size_t` and `set<unsigned int>::iterator`.

Where you can do

```
int i = 0, j = 1;  // OK
```

you are also allowed to do something like

```
for(size_t i = 0, j = 2; ...; ...) ...
```

in a for-loop statement. `i` and `j` in both examples both have the same type, `int` and `size_t` respectively.

Comment: +1 The fist snippet is a *very* concise sample for understanding the problem. Nice.